# PHP "else" and "if" on code for registration script

Tags: php, mysql

I purchased a script a while ago (PHP/MySQL) that contains a user registration form.  The script has an area for selection of Gender (Male or Female).  Two options.

I want to modify this code to allow for selection of an Animal instead of a sex.  I changed the code in all applicable places, and it works great.  The problem is, it only displays animals 1 and 2, since the initial code was setup for a "male/female" selection (2).

I need to find a way for the code to allow for up to 15 animals instead of just 2 results.  Here is the code.  "profile_userinfo_gender1" and "gender2" are what call the "gender" or "animal".  They should go up to "gender15".  Please help!  Thank you!

```
    if ($D->u->gender == 0) $D->gender = $this->lang('profile_userinfo_withoutinfo');
    else {
        if ($D->u->gender == 1) $D->gender = $this->lang('profile_userinfo_gender1');
        else $D->gender = $this->lang('profile_userinfo_gender2');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($D->u->gender == 0) $D->gender = $this->lang('profile_userinfo_withoutinfo');
else {
    $total_gender = 15; //define total gender
    for($i = 1;$i <= $total_gender;$i++){
    if ($D->u->gender == $i) $D->gender = $this->lang("profile_userinfo_gender$i");
     }
    #Add an gender generic default. 
    if ($D->u->gender == $i) $D->gender = $this->lang("profile_userinfo_gender_default");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change from a if else to a for. The if else construct only allows 2 possibilities (even though you could use if elseif elseif.. And so on but that's not nice).

Use a for loop to loop over your 15 possibilities and store some kind of array which gives you the according animals for each value of the gender variable. 
Example:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $animals.length $i++)  {
    if ($D->u->gender == $i){
        $this->lang($animals[i]);
        break;
    } 
}
```

As Norbert van Nobelen mentioned, I'd also strongly recommend [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.org).

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ($D->u->gender == 0) $D->gender = $this->lang('profile_userinfo_withoutinfo');
else {
    if ($D->u->gender == 1) $D->gender = $this->lang('profile_userinfo_gender1');
    else if($D->u->gender == 2) $D->gender =  $this->lang('profile_userinfo_gender2');
    else if($D->u->gender == 3) $D->gender =  $this->lang('profile_userinfo_gender3');
etc...
}
```

There are smarter ways to do this by using a good drop down definition with key and value. See w3schools.org for that.